# What is the purpose of "character_set_server" and "collation_server" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) says the following about "character_set_server" and "collation_server":

> The character_set_server and collation_server system variables
> indicate the server character set and collation.

But I still don't understand what is their purpose, I read somewhere else that their purpose is to set the character set and the collation of newly created databases that don't specify a character set and a collation when created, is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `character_set_server` and `collation_server` are used as defaults if you use CREATE DATABASE without specifying a character set and collation.

Demo:

View the current defaults.

```
mysql> select @@character_set_server, @@collation_server;
+------------------------+--------------------+
| @@character_set_server | @@collation_server |
+------------------------+--------------------+
| utf8mb4                | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change the server defaults in my current session.

```
mysql> set character_set_server=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set collation_server=latin1_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Create a test database, let the defaults take effect.

```
mysql> create database test2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Confirm:

```
mysql> show create database test2;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                                                                        |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test2    | CREATE DATABASE `test2` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */ |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```